# Terraform iterate over list and map in one resource

Tags: terraform

I have resource :

```
resource "aci_epg_to_static_path" "static_ports" {
  for_each           = var.epgs

  application_epg_dn = aci_application_epg.epgs[each.key].id
  tdn                = "topology/pod-1/paths-101/pathep-[eth1/2]"
  encap              = "vlan-${each.value.vlan_id}"
  mode               = "regular"
}
```

Variable file :

```
{
                            },
"epgs":{
         "net-1.1.20.0_24": {"name": "net-1.1.20.0_24",
                                     "bd": "bd_1.1.20.0_24",
                                     "vlan_id": "1000"
                                    },
                 "net-1.1.30.0_24": {"name": "net-1.1.30.0_24",
                                     "bd": "bd_1.1.30.0_24",
                                     "vlan_id": "1001"
                                                 }
        }
"static_ports": ["topology/pod-1/paths-101/pathep-[eth1/2]", 
"topology/pod-1/paths-101/pathep-[eth1/3]"]
}
```

Problem is that I want to use list of strings for **tdn** like:

```
["topology/pod-1/paths-101/pathep-[eth1/2]", "topology/pod-1/paths-101/pathep-[eth1/3]"]
```

and provider resource doesn't support list, only string.

As I'm already using **for_each** to get other variables, it seems to be impossible to loop over list at the same time.

Maybe there is other way to solve this ?

Comment: You would need to change the structure of `var.epgs` from `list(string)` to `map(string)`, and then you can assign a `tdn` per `application_epg_dn`. If you want all of your possible `tdn` per `application_epg_dn`, then this needs to be a `map(list(string))`. Either way, we need to know which of these is your intent, and what your current `var.epgs` looks like.

Comment: What is the structure of your `var.epgs`? Can you show example of it?

Comment: From what I understand, if you want to iterate through two list variables within the same TF resource, you might want to take a look at setproduct function.

Comment: I  updated question with variable file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Caio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6035312/caio-t) for hint.

I made it work without changing variables structure.
Converted var.epgs to list and used setproduct to create new list:

```
> setproduct([for i in var.epgs :"${i.name},${i.vlan_id}"], var.static_ports)
tolist([
  [
    "net-1.1.20.0_24,1000",
    "topology/pod-1/paths-101/pathep-[eth1/2]",
  ],
  [
    "net-1.1.20.0_24,1000",
    "topology/pod-1/paths-101/pathep-[eth1/3]",
  ],
  [
    "net-1.1.30.0_24,1001",
    "topology/pod-1/paths-101/pathep-[eth1/2]",
  ],
  [
    "net-1.1.30.0_24,1001",
    "topology/pod-1/paths-101/pathep-[eth1/3]",
  ],
])
```

So I had to create new loca variable.

```
locals {
  static_path_var = setproduct([for i in var.epgs :"${i.name},${i.vlan_id}"], var.static_ports)
}
```

and then I used this variable in resource :

```
resource "aci_epg_to_static_path" "static_ports" {
  for_each = {
    for i in local.static_path_var : "${i[0]}-${i[1]}" => {
      net_vlan = i[0]
      port_path = i[1]
    }
  }

  application_epg_dn = aci_application_epg.epgs[split(",", each.value.net_vlan)[0]].id
  tdn                = each.value.port_path
  encap              = "vlan-${split(",", each.value.net_vlan)[1]}"
  mode               = "regular"
```

Not sure if it best solution, but it works as expected.